# How can we exactly write a recipe for Linux Test Project to be included in yocto?

Tags: linux, real-time, embedded-linux, yocto, recipe

> I am trying to create a realtime test recipe of Linux Test Project(LTP). But i am not getting starting point of how to start writing recipe for LTP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need to write one as there's already an `ltp` recipe in `openembedded-core` layer (which is duplicated in `poky/meta` layer). c.f. https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/5184/